# I cannot filter the items in redux with reselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, filter

I am working on a react-redux project. My problem is that I cannot filter the items that come from an API according to the user input. I used reselect library but did not work.

Here is my SearchComponent:

```
function SearchComponent({ onClose, isOpen }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const searchAnimes = useSelector(inputItems)

  const filtered = createSelector(inputItems, (items, e) => {
    const filterText = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    const filterWords = filterText.split("")
    items.filter((item) => {
      return filterWords.every((word) =>
        item.title.toLowerCase().includes(word)
      )
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchInputData())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
        "... Some code"
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="You can search for `Kyoukai no Kanata` for example"
          onChange={filtered}
        />
        {searchAnimes.map((el, id) => (
          <div className="searchInput" key={id}>
            <img src={el.images.jpg.small_image_url} alt="" />
            <p>{el.title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Here is my slice:

```
export const fetchInputData = createAsyncThunk(
  "anime/fetchInputData",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}?limit=5`)
    // console.log(response.data.data)
    return response.data.data
  }
)
```

Btw, there is no problem with selector. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterWords = filterText.split("")
```

will break up your string by characters, not by words. I believe you want:

```
const filterWords = filterText.split(" ")
```

Comment: I changed but does not work, still